# Facebook posts not showing on timeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have created webapp in .Net MVC which shares post on Facebook. Here is the code of sharing post

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookAccessToken);
var argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
argList["name"] = postName;
argList.Add("picture", postImageUrl);     
argList["link"] = postUrl;
var actions = new[] { new { name = "More Details", link = morePostDetailsUrl } }.ToList();                    
argList["actions"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actions);
var postResult = fb.Post("<facebookuserId>/feed", argList);
```

Now i am able to post this feed successfully but these posts are not being displayed on timeline. I have checked all permission & they are set to public. Also i can see them in activity logs & on Home screen when i logs in.

1. How to post a feed so that it can be displayed on timeline automatically ?
2. Also i am using actions, are these actions being deprecated or do i need to submit them for review before going live ?

Please guide me if anyone has some idea on the above.
Thanks